# Node.js: Is it possible to catch a "TypeError" and keep the server up?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Somtimes I have a typerror in my code that crashes my server. I'm wondering if there's something I can add so it does not crashes after that happens. Here's more details to the crash:

```
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/lib/imap.js:1019
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:         type: cur[0].toLowerCase(), subtype: cur[1].toLowerCase(),
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:                                                     ^
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Object FILENAME,Oportunidad especial de has no method 'toLowerCase'
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at parseBodyStructure (/app/lib/imap.js:1019:53)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at parseBodyStructure (/app/lib/imap.js:1090:23)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at parseBodyStructure (/app/lib/imap.js:1000:18)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at parseBodyStructure (/app/lib/imap.js:994:13)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at parseFetch (/app/lib/imap.js:974:29)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (/app/lib/imap.js:180:11)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:64:17)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:285:31)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at SecurePair._cycle (tls.js:565:20)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:97:13)
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited
2011-06-08T11:23:09+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried fixing the bug or sanitizing your input?

Comment: I can fix the bug, but I'll probably won't fix all the bugs. I want to be protected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Handle the [`uncaughtException`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/process.html#event_uncaughtException_) event on the process.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Oh shit recover somehow');
});
```

**Warning:** This will catch all exceptions. If you don't bother to handle them properly you can corrupt state very badly.

Comment: Will that caught the one in my example and keep the server going?

Comment: @donald yes. But it does not clean up any connections. The response for whatever client caused the exception will probably hang or crash later. The server wont crash though

Comment: I've tried this in an Electron app and it doesn't work. TypeError aren't caught.